# Malloc in C copying previously allocated strings?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

When i use malloc in C, i use it within different functions and free the pointers i used in malloc outside of the function.

**Function 1**: allocates memory for a point that is a string "hi" it returns the pointer that has "hi"

**function 2:** I have a pointer and allocate memory for this pointer, it then contains "hi" too. Even though i haven't done anything to this pointer.

Why does this happen? How do i stop this?

I've tried to reallocate memory and free multiple times but nothing works.

Comment: Use `calloc` and you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: @JS1, use `calloc()` and you will probably mask the problem; but you will still ***have*** the problem. That will most likely just make it more difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. If you are allocating memory with `malloc`, the library does not initialize the memory to which a pointer is returned. It may contain anything: in your case, it may well contain the same string, but is does not mean anything.

Post your code so we can confirm this diagnostic.